# Error: Program type already present: com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$EnumDescriptorProto$Builder

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After a many hours I decided to share my problem. 
(and after many hours of stackoverflow)

Root build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.binario12.fastpizza"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'


    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.3.0'


    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'

    implementation('com.lamudi.phonefield:phone-field:0.1.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    //Graphic library Material Design
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.0"

    //Recycler view w/ HashMap
    implementation 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.2.0'



    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:16.0.7'


    //PageSliding
    implementation 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.1'


    ///Rating bar
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.3.2'


}
```

I tried also to look the dependencies using the command ./gradlew :app:dependencies and I have seen that protobuf is present in firebase-firestore and in firebase-auth. I tried to don't use the dependencies adding {exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf'} but it didn't work.

All dependencies are set to the last version.
Problems start when i switch from :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
```

to :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I changed

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
```

in this:

```
implementation ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-lite'
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    exclude group: 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite'
    exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos'
}
```

and added

```
implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.10.3'
```

and

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Answer (score -1):

Make this change.
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
to
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'

Comment: I can't. I need to use places:places library

Comment: Matteto, Both 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0' and  'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0' are places library. First one is static library and second one is compatible version of same library. Anyways you have solved it so it might not be required.

Comment: I know but if I implement the compact version I need to change all the code because have different classes. Thank you anyway